# Jersey-media-moxy: APPLICATION_JSON ignoring @XmlElement annotation

Tags: java, json, jersey

I am creating an REST-API with Jersey. To do this I am following a course on PluralSight.

I have installed Jersey 2.2 with the jersey-media-moxy dependency (v2.26). I have the following resource being returned to be parsed into JSON:

```
@XmlRootElement
public class Playlist {
    private int id;
    private String naam;
    private int eigenaarID;
    private Boolean owner;

    public void setData(int id, String naam, int eigenaarID) {
        this.id = id;
        this.naam = naam;
        this.eigenaarID = eigenaarID;

        if(eigenaarID == 0) {
            owner = false;
        } else {
            owner = true;
        }
    }

    @XmlElement(name="id")
    public int getID() {
        return id;
    }

    @XmlElement(name="name")
    public String getNaam() {
        return naam;
    }

    public Boolean getOwner() {
        if(eigenaarID == 0) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    public ArrayList<Track> getTracks(){
        return new ArrayList<Track>();
    }
}
```

If I output XML (with @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)), the property of "getNaam" gets correctly renamed to "name" instead of "naam". When I output JSON (@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)), not only is my property not being renamed, all private properties are being output as well. What is the problem?

Comment: `Application/JSON` doesn't care about XML-specific annotation, as I would expect myself. You will need to look into custom deserializer, or some annotation, that is either a version of `@XmlElement`, but for JSON (and thus will duplicate the meta-information), or works for all medias.

Comment: Don't mix your Jersey dependency versions.

Comment: @peeskillet This was indeed my problem. After all the struggling I choose to go with jackson, so I added `<dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
       <version>2.26</version>
      </dependency>`. At first it didn't work, then I changed the version number to 2.2 (because I am using Jersey 2.2) and then, all of a sudden, it worked. Finally!

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to change it in `@XmlElement(name="name")`.

Comment: That's exactly what it says now, right? 

@XmlElement(name="name")
    public String getNaam() {
        return naam;
    }

Comment: try using jsonIgnore annotation.

Comment: It's not recognized. `@XmlTransient` doesn't work either. `@XmlTransient` is recognized by Eclipse but is not effective.

Comment: add `org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs` to property pacakges in web.xml or java configuration

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using Jackson. I set it up with this [StackOverflow entry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33865290/how-to-ignore-as-well-as-property-editing-for-json-objects-in-jersey-rest).

My MyApplication looks as follows:

```
package com.weijland.spotitube;
import javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath;
import org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig;

@ApplicationPath("services")
public class MyApplication extends ResourceConfig {
    public MyApplication() {
        packages("org.glassfish.jersey.jackson.JacksonFeature");
    }
}
```

And I ended up using this dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
    <version>2.2</version>
</dependency>
```